# Adding widgets to third page causes Frames to adjust size

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, user-interface, tkinter

I've created 3 frames (pages) for my GUI and added a couple of widgets to show a basic framework of my GUI.

I have used the `.grid_propagate(0)` method to stop my frames from adjusting size based on the widgets within them.

See below for code:

```
from Tkinter import *
# from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
# from Function_Sheet import *
# from time import sleep
# import ttk, ttkcalendar, tkSimpleDialog, csv, pyodbc, threading
# from Queue import Queue
# import os
# cwd = os.getcwd()


class CA_GUI:

    def __init__(self, master):
        ### Configure ###
        win_colour = '#D2B48C'
        master.title('CA 2.0'), master.geometry('278x289'), master.configure(background='#EEE5DE')
        win1, win2, win3 = Frame(master, background=win_colour, bd=5, relief=GROOVE, pady=10, padx=20, width=260, height = 270), Frame(master, background=win_colour, bd=5, relief=GROOVE, pady=10, padx=20, width=260, height = 270), Frame(master, background=win_colour, bd=5, relief=GROOVE, pady=10, padx=20, width=260, height = 270)

        ### Grid Frames ###
        for window in [win1,win2,win3]:
            window.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news', pady=10, padx=10)
            window.grid_propagate(0)

        ### Window 1 ###
        self.win1_label1 = Label(win1, text = 'This is page 1!')
        self.win1_label1.pack(fill = X, side = TOP)

        self.win1_button1 = Button(win1, text = 'Close', command = master.quit)
        self.win1_button1.pack(fill = X, side = BOTTOM)

        self.win1_button2 = Button(win1, text = 'Page 2', command = lambda:self.next_page(win2))
        self.win1_button2.pack(fill = X, side = BOTTOM)

        ### Window 2 ###
        self.win2_label1 = Label(win2, text = 'This is page 2!')
        self.win2_label1.pack(fill = X, side = TOP)

        self.win2_button1 = Button(win2, text = 'Close', command = master.quit)
        self.win2_button1.pack(fill = X, side = BOTTOM)

        self.win2_button2 = Button(win2, text = 'Page 3', command = lambda:self.next_page(win3))
        self.win2_button2.pack(fill = X, side = BOTTOM)

        ### Window 3 ###
        self.win3_label1 = Label(win3, text = 'This is page 3!')
        self.win3_label1.pack(fill = X, side = TOP)

        win1.tkraise()

    def next_page(self, window):
        window.tkraise()

root = Tk()
b = CA_GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The problem comes when I'm adding widgets to `win3`. If I comment out the code relating to `win3`, all the frames stay at their specified size and everything looks good. However, adding even a simple label widget to win3, the frames sizes seem to adjust to the size of their widgets. - This is not what I want!

P.S.

The issue does not seem to be exclusive to `win3` as commenting out another frames widgets solves the re-sizing issue.

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: note: `grid_propagate(0)` won't have any effect if you use `pack` to put the widgets in the frame. You have to use `pack_propagate` if you're using `pack`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is to never turn off geometry propagation. It's almost always the wrong choice. Tkinter does a fantastic job of efficiently laying out widgets. Let the frame shrink (or grow) to fit the contents, and use the geometry manager to cause the frame to fit the space allotted to it.

The problem in this code is that you aren't allowing grid to allocate all of the space to the frames.  You need to give at least one row and one column "weight" so that grid will allocate extra space to that row and column, forcing the frames to fill the space rather than shrink.

Change the one section of your code to look like this:

```
### Grid Frames ###
master.grid_rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
master.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)

for window in [win1,win2,win3]:
    window.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='news', pady=10, padx=10)
```

This all works because you're giving an explicit size to the main window. In a sense, setting a fixed size for the window turns off the automatic re-sizing of the window based on its immediate children. With the re-sizing turned off, and the proper use of grid options, the inner frames will fill the window.

Of course, if you put widgets that are too big to fit, they will be chopped off. Such is the price you pay for using explicit sizes rather than letting tkinter grow or shrink to fit.

Comment: Thank you Brian. Your answer explains everything very well and straightens out the issues I was having. Kind Regards, Luke.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your three windows, you are packing the widgets, not griding them. So all what you need to do is to change this line:

```
window.grid_propagate(0)
```

to:

```
window.pack_propagate(0)
```

After doing so, you will get what you expect:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. However, if I were to use pack, all three windows are placed vertically and are all visible straight away. This is not what I need unfortunatley!

Comment: You are welcome.  I see one window per time when I run your program following the modification above as you can see from the screenshot I took.

Comment: I can see that! :) I would post my own screenshot but am unable to in the comments!

Comment: Strange :) But anyway, I am happy for you that the other answer is helpful.

Comment: Live long and prosper, brother.